# giving apps permission to drive or gmail

Tags: gmail, google-drive

If you give mailsapps or filemanagers on Android (those with a few millions users and likely trustable) access to your gmail-account or google drive, do they in general store these data (mails/files) on their servers as well? Or is it relatively safe to give them this permission?

Comment: For GDrive I can't answer your question but for Dropbox I know that there is a authentication mode that allows the app only to access a special app specific subfolders in the apps folder in Dropbox.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Though this question is relatively incomplete and off-topic, I'll still try to answer it.

Whenever you login with Google on an application, you can find whatever access that specific app/service has over your Google account by visiting accounts.google.com and thus decide whether it's safe for your privacy or not.

**Now regarding whether these services can store your data on their servers is upto them and would be explicitly mentioned in the Terms of Serive / Terms and Conditions/ Privacy Policy of that particular app/service**

That's it and one thing you should always keep in mind, doesn't matter it's a "free" service from Google or any other company,

> "When something is free, you're the product"